# Show message status in html page with PHP - Contact forum

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have my PHP set up it works fine so far with my contact form (I'm a 'Newbie' in PHP).

I am using `echo` to display the status of the message (if it is sent or not). once the user clicks the send button, the status message shows in a new URL - the URL of the PHP file (somesite.com/forum.php)

My Question is can I have my status message displayed with in my html file the file where my forum is (Forum.html) basicly instead of hitting the send button and then the URL changing to forum.php can I have the URL remain the same `(Forum.html)` and just possibly but the status text in there (the html file).

Here is my code:

```
<?php

       $email = $_POST['email'];
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       $message = $_POST['message'];
       $from = 'From: Datcroft Website';
       $to = 'myemail@hotmail.co.uk';
       $subject = 'Datcroft Site Message';

       $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message: $message\n";

       if ($_POST['submit']) {
           if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
           echo '<center><font color="lightgray"><p>Message Sent Successfully!</p> <p>I will get back in touch as soon as possible.</p></font></center>';
           } else {
           echo '<center><font color="lightgray"><p>Ah! Try again, please?</p></font></center>';
           }
       }
    ?>
```

The Message Status part of my code(the thing i want to display in the forum.html not a new url:

```
 echo '<center><font color="lightgray"><p>Message Sent Successfully!</p> <p>I will get back in touch as soon as possible.</p></font></center>';
               } else {
               echo '<center><font color="lightgray"><p>Ah! Try again, please?</p></font></center>';
```

Thanks to anyone who can point my in the right direction !
Thank You In Advanced.

Comment: You'd need to submit your form with something like AJAX

Comment: you could could change forum.html to forum.php and let it send the data to itself ... and copy your echo-code into that site

Comment: Ah I suppose JQuery could do the job also? if there is no PHP solution.

Comment: @ChrisLad No need to involve JS here – this is a basic task, that was solved in PHP in many different ways and implemented in many frameworks…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `forum.html` file to `forum.php`, then move your PHP code to the top of your new `forum.php` file, and submit your form to self:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

And then place your if where you want to show the message.

Comment: There is even a German Wikipedia entry on this method: ["Affenformular"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affenformular) – I don't know if there is a related term in English. It means literally "ape form" and suggest, that even an ape pressing submit over and over again, can't do any harm or good without filling in proper form values.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can redirect back from forum.php with a flash message (A variable saved in the session and that gets deleted once used one time) and display it on html if it's set

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit sleepy, just change from html to PHP extension

Comment: [Please avoid redirects](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-11-avoid-redirects-7209.html) – a form.php that submits to itself is a good solution.

Comment: Why? If form is submitting to itself you give poor user experience in the case user wants to refresh page, because form data will be sent againt and user will be prompted with alert message